# how to solve this chain rule problem

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm having some difficulty solving this problem. The information I have is the following:

$z:(y_1,y_2,y_3,\dotsc,y_n)$ and $y$ is also composed of a function $y:(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_n)$
given $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y_i}$ is known and $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y_i \partial y_j}$ also given , find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_n}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, $y_1$, $y_2$, ..., $y_n$ are $n$ variables. Each one is a function of the $n$ variables $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$ (the same number of variables). Finally, $z$ is a function of $y_1$, $y_2$, ..., $y_n$. Do you know the expressions of $y_1$, $y_2$, ..., $y_n$ in terms of $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$? And do you now the expression of $z$ in terms of $y_1$, $y_2$, ..., $y_n$?

Comment: You understood what I mean, and no this is all what is given, I don't need a value answer just a conceptual one, supposing i have the first degree partial derivatives of z and the second degree derivatives of z also, I need to find the first derivative of z but derived with respect to x

Comment: Well, you'd need to know something about the relationship between the $y$'s and the $x$'s. I think it might be a good idea to include the text of the problem verbatim.